# Windows 10 - CPU frequency at 0,4 Ghz and 100% CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu, power-management

I have following problem.
Sometimes the CPU in my laptop has frequency changed to 0,4Ghz and CPU usage is at 100%.
This can take few minutes and it takes at least 20-30 seconds to wake up laptop from this state.
I attached [Intel XTU screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfFu7.png) with this behaviour.
I'm using Best Performance power profile and charger. (it's not on the battery)

My laptop is Lenovo Carbon X1, CPU i7-7500U. Windows 10 10.0.19041.
Everything is updated. (system, drivers etc.)

What can I do more ?

Comment: I have a ThinkPad X1 Carbon here with i7 CPU. I do not have this issue. Are you sure both BIOS (should be V1.45 or something near) and Chipset have been updated as well?

Comment: `10.0.19041` - are you sure this is the build you are running.  10.0.19041 is a Windows 10 Insider Preview build.  Have you tried running 10.018363 on the device?

Comment: I had the same problem with older build. I'm using Insider Preview to have WSL2. BIOS 1.44

Comment: The question is how to log CPU state behaviour. Any program for this ?

Answer (score 1):

When this happens have you left the laptop idle for a while? How CPU's function can be pretty complicated, so perhaps somebody can explain why or if this happens better, but I believe it has to do with the CPU basically waking up from being idle by a system process. Are you using Windows? Try sorting task manager by CPU usage in the process panel, and let it idle for sometime, then see what process is grabbing all the cycles.

**Check #1** 
[image]

**Check #2**
[image]

Comment: I would always let any computer rest for 30 seconds before closing the lid, but otherwise I have not see what you said above going back to 2008 laptops and newer.

Comment: What I mean is do you leave the laptop open and running and when you come back and start doing things on it does this problem seem to occur? Or when you opened up from sleep perhaps? Or does it happen randomly while your actively using it. If its the latter you should open task manager on processes and sort by the CPU column, theirs probably an app hogging all your resources, though it could be a virus, though it probably an app you just don't realize is still running. Also it sounds like your using a beta version of Windows, which by their very nature can be potentially unstable.

Comment: I have a ThinkPad with V2004 running and it suspends just fine and recovers properly as well.

Comment: Yes but it could be a bug thats undocumented in the beta version, can you rollback to vanilla and see if the problem continues to occur or will that reset your apps? I've never used a Window's Insider build before, not sure I'd trust it, considering the "stable" version has forced me to do a complete system repair twice, both times after deleting my mouse and keyboard drivers after an update so I couldn't sign in. You ever had to go into windows system repair on a desktop? You literally have unplug the computer in the boot sequence several times in order to convince it that its broken.

Comment: You fix it by breaking it. Its like if Monty Python made an OS.

Comment: I have been running Windows Insider builds for nearly a year now. The V200x series have been very good.

Comment: Still the important thing is to see what processes are using the CPU, most processes only use a couple percentage points at a time, in say a decent quad core it should be easy to see what program is causing it to got to 100%.,  Also right click on the graph in the CPU tab and change graph from overall utilization to logical processor it'll split it  into multiple graphs depending on the number of cores and make sure there all being utilized.,It could be if you have say a quad-core that only one of the cores is working and therefore thats why its processor speed is low and its using a 100%

Comment: The problem is when I'm leaving my laptop idle. 100% CPU usage is because of very low frequency. Then waking up from idle can take 20-30 seconds before frequency change to something normal.

Comment: When you say idle do you waking it up from sleep or leaving it idle in sense of leaving it on and not in sleep. What applications are running according to task manager? Are all your cores being utilized according to the task manager. Next time you leave it idle have task manager open and sorted by CPU utilization and see what applications are open and how much of that 100% they are using.